# Android Studio - Cannot Resolve Symbol items in Array Adapter

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-arrayadapter

I am currently trying to implement a Bluetooth connection in an Android application using a few different tutorials and am running into issues trying to add detected paired devices to a ListView for the user to choose from.

It is currently throwing the error "Cannot resolve symbol items" in the line below, but I'm not sure what to replace items with or if that's the only issue.
itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

I would really appreciate it if someone could correct my syntax in the Java code.

Thanks!

Java Code

```
package com.example.khite.wheelnav;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.Set;

public class ConnectActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1234;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connect);

        // Create Bluetooth Adapter
        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
                Intent intent;
                intent = new Intent(this, NoBluetoothActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        }

        // Enable Bluetooth
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }

        // Create an Array Adapter to Add Devices to
        ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter;
        itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

        //Query Paired Devices
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        // If there are paired devices
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            // Loop through paired devices
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                itemsAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        }

        // Add Paired Devices to a List View
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
    }

    public void openChooseFunctionActivity(View view){
        //open choose function activity
            Intent intent;
            intent = new Intent(this, ChooseFunctionActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

XML Code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.khite.wheelnav.ConnectActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Continue"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="openChooseFunctionActivity"
        android:background="#ff8180fd"
        android:textColor="#ff000000" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initialized first your items collection, then an adapter

```
            //Query Paired Devices
            Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
            // If there are paired devices
            List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
            if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                // Loop through paired devices
                for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                    // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                    items.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                }
            }

           // Create an Array Adapter to Add Devices to
            ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter;
            itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
```

Answer (score 0):

"items" in your code is not initalized at all. You have to pass a String[] or List<String> object as the last parameter of the [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) constructor.

"Cannot resolve symbol x" generally means variable x cannot be found.

Comment: That worked, thanks!  I added List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); and used the empty list object to initialize the Array Adapter before adding the devices to it.